# Error when requesting User.history.all ()

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model class User (AbstractUser), I would like to keep track of the User history, but I have an error while getting `User.history.all ()`,

```
ERROR: table "core_user" is missing from the FROM clause
LINE 1: SELECT "core_user". "Id", "core_user". "Password", "core_user" ...

SELECT "core_user"."id", "core_user"."password", "core_user"."last_login", '
'"core_user"."is_superuser", "core_user"."username", '
'"core_user"."first_name", "core_user"."last_name", "core_user"."email", '
'"core_user"."is_staff", "core_user"."is_active", "core_user"."date_joined", '
'"core_user"."editor_config", "dib_page_historicaluser"."ip_address", '
'"dib_page_historicaluser"."history_id", '
'"dib_page_historicaluser"."history_date", '
'"dib_page_historicaluser"."history_change_reason", '
'"dib_page_historicaluser"."history_type", '
'"dib_page_historicaluser"."history_user_id" FROM "dib_page_historicaluser" '
'ORDER BY "dib_page_historicaluser"."history_date" DESC, '
'"dib_page_historicaluser"."history_id" DESC LIMIT 21')
```

`core_user` table is my `base_model`, and `dib_page_historicaluser` table is the history model.

Comment: Did you run this commands ``python manage.py makemigrations`` and ``python manage.py migrate``

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari, 
 yes, I can't understand why the queryset creates such a query, it's just that even in the console, the query HistoricalUser.objects.all () produces the same error

Comment: @Community
t's just that even in the pycharm console the request HistoricalUser.objects.all () gives the same error